# How do I say "First week of December" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, time

How do I say "First week of December" in German? Is the formulation in the following sentence correct?

> Im Dezember ersten Wochenendes ging ich einkaufen.

Comment: You have to use another sequence of words: "Am ersten Wochenende des Dezembers ging ich einkaufen". But week = Woche and weekend = Wochenende are two different words and meanings. When week is used the sentence is different: "In der ersten Dezemberwoche ging ich einkaufen." Another possibility: "Am ersten Dezemberwochenende ging ich einkaufen.

Comment: "Wochenende" = weekend, "Woche" = week. So apart from being bad (but understandable), it is also wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> Erste Dezemberwoche

Your sentence would look like this:

> In der ersten Dezemberwoche ging ich einkaufen.

Comment: Right. By the way, "im Dezember ersten Wochenendes" is wrong.

Comment: But one can say ' Im Dezember letzten Jahres' , right?

Comment: Yes. Mind the difference that *Jahres* ist the greater entity here. If you want to do something similar with *Woche*, this will work: „*In der ersten Woche des letzten Dezembers*“. The article *des* is needed here while it can be left out with *letzten Jahres*. You can also say „*Im Dezember des letzten Jahres*”, which would semantically equivalent.